# Allowing only the current user to the edit page in grails

Tags: spring, url, grails, spring-security

I am building a web portal in grails with spring security. In my portal The users having `USER`, `ADMIN` role has the privilege to edit their profile. By login in USER role go to edit page `/RITE/user/myedit/2` and can edit. Problem is when i editing the url  `/RITE/user/myedit/2` , by `/RITE/user/myedit/1` I am able to see the ADMI privileged user. I tried annotations, but didnt work . How can I avoid this?

```
@Secured(['ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_USER'])
def mylist(Integer max)
{
    def user = springSecurityService.currentUser
    def c= User.findByUsername(user.username)
    params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
    [userInstanceList: c]

}
@Secured(['ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_USER'])
def myshow(Long id) {
    //userService.show(id)
    //println "in myshow"
    def user = springSecurityService.currentUser
    UserDetails currentUser = springSecurityService.principal
            if(id==currentUser.id){
            def userInstance = User.get(id)
            if (!userInstance) {
                flash.message = message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'user.label', default: 'User'), id])
                redirect(action: "mylist")
                return
            }
        [userInstance: userInstance]
        }
    }
@Secured(['ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_USER'])
def myedit(Long id) {
    def user = springSecurityService.currentUser
    UserDetails currentUser = springSecurityService.principal
    def c= User.findByUsername(user.username)
        if(id == user.id ){
        def userInstance = User.get(c.id)
        if (!userInstance) {
            flash.message = message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'user.label', default: 'User'), id])
            println("not allowed")
            redirect(action: "mylist")
            return
        }

        [userInstance: userInstance]
    }
}
```

Comment: you write "I tried annotations, but didnt work" -- what did you tried? - You should post that you tried!

Comment: @Ralph I edited the my post

Answer (score 1):

You need a manual implementation of something that express:

```
if( User.findByUsername(springSecurityService.currentUser.username).id
          != id_ofEditedUser) {
    throw new AccessDeniedException("one can only edit its own stuff");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ralph's suggestion is accurate but I don't generally do it this way when we're talking about user information that is only editable by the authenticated user.  You'd be better off not requiring an ID at all:

```
def myedit() {

   // this is the authenticated user, therefor, this is the information being edited
   def userInstance = User.findByUsername(springSecurityService.principal.username)
   [userInstance: userInstance]

}
```

If you want the ability for someone other than the specific user to edit user info, an Admin for example, provide an administrative action specifically for that.  It will make more sense 6 months from now when have to look at the code again.

Comment: I provided a Admin the privilege to edit others. really helped.